# What is the difference between an Ethereum client and Ethereum API?

Tags: clients, external-api

Pardon me if this is silly, but as per my limited observation, the number of APIs is higher than the number of clients that exist. How are APIs different from clients?

Comment: I think you will need to define Ethereum API to get a good answer on this forum. Can you share where you have found 'more apis' compares to clients?

Comment: What I meant was, there are clients like geth(go client) and CPP client, and APIs like for Clojure.

Answer (score 2):

Ethereum doesn't have an API, as it is understood in the traditional web. It has only **one** [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) which outlines the methodologies which **should** be implemented by all clients. However, we live in an imperfect world, hence sometimes different clients find or produce different problems (see geth and parity).

Despite the aforementioned clarification, I think you are referring to the asymmetry between light nodes and full nodes. It's hard to track these numbers, we run a distributed network here after all, but [ethstats.net](https://ethstats.net/) provide some pretty good rough estimates.

The number of light nodes is definitely higher than full nodes, but the former are extremely useful to the ecosystem. They prevent full nodes from colluding, because the client software should be forked too if one wants to have users accept a malicious split. Vitalik has written a great article on [coordination problems](https://vitalik.ca/general/2017/05/08/coordination_problems.html).